# Rails: Is it possible to select has_many association column id as array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have following models and has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, when I select my products

```
products =  Product.where()....,
```

is it possible to select the associated stores ids or other store column as array in my query? so I can do

```
products[0].store_ids
```

to check what stores it belongs to.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :store
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

Comment: I think you could use `includes` when querying for products, later you can collect associated `:store_ids` as an array for the product you want. Like `products = Product.includes(:stores).where('your query')` then `products[0].stores.collect{|store| store.id}`

Comment: But that could return duplicate products right? since one product can be longs to many stores

Comment: then you could append `distinct` at the end to get the unique records @user1883793

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`store_ids` is a magic method that `has_and_belongs_to_many` defines on `Product`'s instance methods.

> **collection_singular_ids**
>
> Returns an array of the associated objects' ids.

[See this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many%20%22See%20this%22%20for%20more%20info.) for more info.

You don't have to eager load your associations, but it's a very good idea.  As long as you have:

```
products = Product.includes(:stores)
```

Then you can call `products[0].store_ids` to get a list of store ids.

If you want to query on that association, you can do

```
Product.includes(:stores).where(stores: {some_field: 'Some Value'})
```

### EDIT

If you want to get all unique products with their store ids, you can use `array_agg` with a `group by` since you're using Postgres.

```
products = Product
           .joins(:stores)
           .select('products.id, products.name, products.whichever_fields..., array_agg(stores.id) AS store_id_array')
           .group('products.id, products.name, products.whichever_fields...')
```

Then you will have `products[0].store_id_array`.  Don't use `store_ids` since that will call the method defined by the `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: Again, the include will return duplicate products for each store, is it possible to select all the ids in my query something like .select('stores.id') and prevent duplicate. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
products =  Product.where(name: 'Magic Unicorn Spray').includes(:stores) #  ...
store_ids = products[0].stores.pluck(:id)
```

Comment: there is no method `stores` on `ActiveRecord::Relation` array `products`. Only one record `products` has a method `stores`. in your example can be `products.first.stores.pluck(:id)`

Comment: Ooops, I meant to write `products[0].stores.pluck(:id)`. Edited answer. Thanks @Зелёный

Answer (score -1):

you could simply use `includes` and `distinct` when querying for products, later you can collect associated :store_ids as an array for the product you want. Like

`products = Product.includes(:stores).where('your query').distinct`

then
`products[0].stores.collect{|store| store.id}`

now you don't get any duplicate records. I think would help you.Thanks